# How to use 2 observer in same event in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, sales-order

I want to use 2 observer on 'sales_order_place_after' this observer as i have checked if i place one observer it works fine but how can i run 2 observer with one event.

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_place_after"
              instance="Hl\SendEmail\Observer\CustomerNewOrderObserver"/>
    <observer name="hl_sales_order_place_after" instance="Hl\SendEmail\Observer\AfterOrderObserver" />
</event>
```

here oage got stuck on checkout and nothing happens.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: <event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_place_after" instance="Hl\SendEmail\Observer\CustomerNewOrderObserver"/>
</event>
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="hl_sales_order_place_after" instance="Hl\SendEmail\Observer\AfterOrderObserver" />
</event>

Comment: you need to use separate event node for each obsever

Comment: @Pawan thanks for your response Yes i have used that too but it also gives me an error in xml for using same event name.

Comment: It shows this error Element 'event': Duplicate key-sequence ['sales_order_place_after'] in unique identity-constraint 'uniqueEventName'